# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Ashley Nunn]
[image: John Cavan]
[image: Baarn]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Sorry to disturb but I thought you said **volunteered** their time. I didn't see 1 of them volunteering in [Who do we want as moderators?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/59/who-do-we-want-as-moderators?cb=1). or does **volunteering** have another meaning.

Comment: Congratulations to the new mods!

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi the Community Managers have asked us (and probably others) directly by email if we would like to volunteer. In the meta discussion you linked to, Ashley Nunn and John Cavan actually did volunteer  (highest voted answers). While I considered nominating myself I didn't as I have no previous experience as a moderator on the StackExchange network. As mentioned before the results of that discussion on meta are not binding to the Community Managers and they ultimately decide who they see fit as pro tempore mods, based on several factors I can only speculate about.

Comment: Yay!  Excellent choices.  Congrats!

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi - if you're curious to observe factors that would IMHO make a good "evaluation-selected" moderator, go look at Baarn's activity log on his meta and main accounts  for this site. His responses / comments are thorough, even-tempered, and show core experience with the system. His participation is consistent, but not obsessive.  The only drawback I can find are occasional minor issues with grammar and spelling, but that's understandable and can be corrected. And from a network standpoint, he's well distributed across several sites and has been around for at least 2 years.

Comment: @JoshDM nice analysis.

Comment: Thanks all, I hope we can all live up to your expectations. Please remember, as well, that our chat room is a great way to reach out to us if you need assistance on the site and all of us hang out there from time to time anyways.

Comment: @Baarn Okay and Congratulations!!!!!!

Comment: @JoshDM he, stop stalking me :D

Comment: @Baarn - spell it "tackle" and not "takle" and I will. :)

Comment: Congratulations to our new mods!  Thanks for being willing to put in the time and effort to help keep this site on track :)

Comment: Why exactly is it that pro tem moderators are only temporarily moderators and can't remain moderators after the elections if they've been active?

Comment: @John Our ideal scenario is having moderators that the community elects, versus those that we appoint based on likely merit. Pro-tem mods see the site through until it graduates, and then we have an election. It's _very_ common for the pro-tem mods to run in the first election and win. We can't have an election early on, because the size of the community is just too small to sustain one.

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations....!!!!

[image]

Comment: +1. Waiting for pro-tem moderators to exercise their newly-granted abilities to lock this post from unwanted "me toos". :P

Comment: @JoshDM - But look at the nice flowers!