# Please welcome your new moderator, James Jenkins!

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm pleased to announce a new addition to the Pets SE moderator team:

[image: profile for James Jenkins at Pets Stack Exchange, Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers]

James is joining the ranks of the team since [Baarn doesn't seem able to continue](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/728/do-we-need-to-add-another-moderator-pro-tem). I've tried to contact him several times without luck, we need a full team while I continue to try and make sure he's okay. Baarn did a *fantastic* job in his role as a moderator and helped to bring Pets SE out of its infancy, we owe him our thanks and hope that he'll be back soon!

James joins the team as a fantastic contributor that is always warm and helpful to new users, a passionate lover of animals and a well-articulated fellow. Give him a warm welcome, and remember - we're all learning on this adventure.

Welcome, James! It's great to have you on board.

Answer (score 11):

Thank you, I hope to meet the same level of excellence that has been shown by all the moderators of this site.

Comment: Welcome aboard!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Hooray and congrats!

Comment: Awesome and Congratulations!!!!!!!